# Organizar archivos con python

Tags: python, python-3.x

espero me puedan ayudar, tengo una carpeta /logs que contiene N cantidad de archivos .json todos inician con un nombre por ejemplo:

daniel_20210413.json
felipe_20210211.json

como puedo ordenarlos por carpetas? que dentro de la carpeta /logs ya sea que se cree una carpeta por nombre o que yo mismo las cree pero que el script las organice:

```
/logs
     /daniel
            daniel_20210413.json


/logs
     /felipe
            felipe_20210211.json
```

he visto que usan import shutil pero no logro entender como funciona o como crearlo.

gracias a todos!

Answer (score 1):

Lo siguiente podría funcionar:

- Haciendo uso de `os.listdir()` obtienes todos los nombres de fichero de la carpeta actual, y te quedas con los que terminen en `.json`. Vas guardando esos nombres en un diccionario cuya clave será lo que haya antes del `_` ("daniel", "fernando", etc) y cuyo valor será una lista de ficheros que comienzan de ese modo.
- Una vez hemos terminado lo anterior tenemos un diccionario cuyas claves son las carpetas a crear y cuyos contenidos son los ficheros que han de ir a cada carpeta.
- Iterando sobre ese diccionario, se van creando las carpetas con `os.mkdir()` y se van moviendo a ellas los ficheros, con `shutil.move()`.

Por tanto el código sería este:

```
import os
import shutil
from collections import defaultdict

# Primero crear el diccionario con la información
carpetas = defaultdict(list)
for f in os.listdir():
  if f.endswith("json"):
    nombre, _ = f.split("_")
    carpetas[nombre].append(f)

# Después usar ese diccionario para crear carpetas y mover ficheros
for carpeta, ficheros in carpetas.items():
  os.mkdir(carpeta)
  for f in ficheros:
    shutil.move(f, carpeta)
```

Debes ejecutar este script estando dentro de la carpeta `logs`. Para que se pueda ejecutar más veces si aparecen más ficheros deberías manejar las excepciones que podrían producirse al tratar de crear una carpeta ya existente.